# Datetime field overflow error in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench

I am trying to insert into a mysql table after conversion from mssql. The datetime format was in hexadecimal, Then i wrote a function for converting it to datetime. When i try to insert the values, I am getting datetime field overflow error.

My insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT into BankMaster (BankCode, BankName, CREATEDID, CREATEDDATETIME, UPDATEDID, UPDATEDDATETIME) VALUES ('N','xxxx','admin',cast(ConvertSQLServerDate(0x98A90076) as datetime), NULL, NULL);
```

Function is as follows:

```
create function ConvertSQLServerDate(dttm binary(16))
returns datetime
return CAST(
 '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
  INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
  INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND AS DATETIME);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had generated script with smalldatetime as data type in MSSQL. So I was getting an 8bit hexadecimal number. Later on, I converted into datetime datatype which resulted in 16bit hexadecimal value and I got my desired result.